# Rsync does not preserve permissions while rsyncing from Android to Laptop

Tags: sync, file-permissions, rsync

I am trying to do rsync from my android phone to my laptop.  The problem that I am facing is that the permissions are not getting preserved even when the `-p` flag  is used. I have also used the other flags such as `-o`, `-g`.

What may be the reason and a fix for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your SD card formatted as FAT32? If so, that's why - it's a FAT32 limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this `rsync -rltDv --chmod=u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX`